# gRPC support for Angular

Tags: angular, grpc

I believe there is a way to call gRPC service using Angular but I can't find any official documentation from Angular side to call gRPC service.

Is there any roadmap to officially support gRPC calls from Angular?

Comment: I've been using grpc-web successfully at work with Angular (not that it really matters but I do happen to use Angular as well). https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web as a little addition to this, when you manage to get up and running if you want to e2e test your app we've published last week a tiny package on NPM to mock the grpc calls/responses https://github.com/cloudnc/grpc-web-testing-toolbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither on [gRPC-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/382) side nor on [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38566) side an official support is planned at this point. However there is a third party library [ngx-grpc](https://github.com/ngx-grpc/ngx-grpc) which you could use, it seems to be well maintained.